# LLVM | insert hook function with uintptr_t argument

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I want to insert below function:

```
void foo(uintptr_t addr) {}
```

Function type declaration:

```
std::vector<llvm::Type*> params = {Type::getInt64Ty(Context)};
FunctionType* funcTy = FunctionType::get(Type::getVoidTy(Context), params, false);
```

Call insertion:

```
llvm::IRBuilder<> builder(I);
builder.SetInsertPoint(bb, ++builder.GetInsertPoint());
// uintptr_t addr = 123213
ArrayRef< Value* > args(ConstantInt::get(Type::getInt64Ty(llvmContext), addr, false));
builder.CreateCall(F,args);
```

Got: Calling a function with a bad signature!"' failed.

Please help with the correct way of doing this

Comment: The parameter you add is an int, not a pointer to int.

Comment: Thanks but could you be more specific about the exact code changes I need to make?

Comment: Yes, when I am back at my keyboard, in a week's time.

Comment: Well, I'm back, but on closer inspection I don't think I can give you exact code. Youc call to `ConstantInt::get()` gives you a constant integer from a constant integer. This implies that you have a constant integer, but what you want isn't even an integer, it's an pointer to an integer. Are you trying to pass an integer by reference? I can't tell what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

@arnt is correct. I guess you want the "addr" as an int to your hook function. **Remember, this addr can't be statically determined by the compiler, but it's a dynamic address.** So you need to replace your args with something like:

```
ArrayRef< Value* > args(CastInst::CreateIntegerCast(addr, F->getFunctionType()->getFunctionParamType(0), true, "", InsertPoint))
```

You can use your IRBuilder to do this. This is actually instrument a new instruction to dynamically convert an "addr" into a integer, then you can pass it to your hook function.